# Problema Datepicker en Modal con js

Tags: javascript, datepicker

tengo un problema con mi datepicker en un modal, al querer seleccionar el año o el mes no carga  como en el siguiente [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sudiptabanerjee/93eTU/)

les comparto el codigo que estoy usando

```
function FechaNacimientoFecha(){
    var date    = new Date();
    var anho    = date.getYear + 1;

    $('#fecNacimientoCargo').daterangepicker({ 
        format              :   'DD/MM/YYYY',
        startDate           :   '01/01/',
        endDate             :   '31/12/',
        minDate             :   '01/01/1930',
        maxDate             :   '31/12/',
        singleDatePicker    :   true,
        showDropdowns       :   true,
        parentEl: '#fecNacimientoCargo',
        showWeekNumbers     :   false,
        opens   :'center',

        "locale": {
            "separator": " - ",
            "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
            "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
            "fromLabel": "DE",
            "toLabel": "HASTA",
            "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "Dom",
                "Lun",
                "Mar",
                "Mie",
                "Jue",
                "Vie",
                "S&aacute;b"
            ],
            "monthNames": [
                "Enero",
                "Febrero",
                "Marzo",
                "Abril",
                "Mayo",
                "Junio",
                "Julio",
                "Agosto",
                "Septiembre",
                "Octubre",
                "Noviembre",
                "Diciembre"
            ],
            "firstDay": 1
      }});

    $('#fecNacimientoCargo').val('');
    $('#fecNacimientoCargo').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate("\"01/01/+" + anho + "\"");
}
```

Comment: En el link que pusiste funciona bien.

Comment: pero debes probar el intentar seleccionar un año o un mes... a mi me queda como en fantasma

Comment: A mi me funciona bien.

Comment: mm está raro, problé el link que pasas y como dices, si le doy click en el año o mes no me carga el select, le tuve que dar como 10 clicks y lo tomó, obviamente no es la idea

Comment: sabes como puedo arreglar eso? Por lo que investigue, es que el datepicker queda "detras" del modal y es por eso que hace ese efecto fantasma

Comment: Para evitar ese problema con el modal es que creo la clase css .clsDatePicker {
    z-index: 100000;
}                                                                                                                      , puedes probar agreando eso